# C : POSIX threads library test-suite

Tags: c, multithreading, unit-testing, posix, test-suite

I'm working on a thread library which implement user level threads (i have something like pthread_setscope which works) and I'm looking for some set of tests to avoid writing one for every function I implement (mutexes, conditions, etc ...)

Does anyone know something like that?

Comment: Did you just reply to yourself? O.o

Comment: Yeah, I did, while no one seems to answer, I just searched by myself and posted the answer I found. I hoped for a quick answer here but finally i did it myself :)

Comment: Did you just down vote for this reason? O.o

Comment: I didn't down vote, actually I will upvote now since the answer is quite useful :)

Comment: I've just received my first down vote and i'm wondering where and why :)
Thought it was you, sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the [OpenGroup POSIX Threads Test Suite](http://www.opengroup.org/testing/testsuites/vsthover.htm) :

> The test suite can be run in the following modes :
>
> - POSIX 1003.1-1996 mode, covering Pthreads only.
> - UNIX 98 mode, covering Pthreads and the XSH5 extensions
> - POSIX 1003.1-2003 mode
> - UNIX 03 mode
>
> This allows the test suite to easily be used during development of your threads implementation, for example initially you might only want to run the POSIX 1003.1-1996 subset.
>
> The assertion counts are as follows:
>
> - POSIX 96 MODE: PTHR.hdr 286, PTHR.os 445
> - UNIX98 MODE: PTHR.hdr 365, PTHR.os 563

There is also the [IEEE POSIX Certification Test Suites](http://get.posixcertified.ieee.org/docs/testsuites.html).

Finally you can have a look at the [Open POSIX Test Suite](http://posixtest.sourceforge.net/).